# openshift websphere liberty profile installation

Tags: websphere, openshift

I am new boy to openshift and planning to move my env to open shift.

trying to install websphre liberty profile on open shift, but getting the below exception

1)from openshift console...

```
The cartridge manifest at 'https://github.com/WASdev/cloud.openshift.cartridge.wlp' could not be downloaded: The cartridge manifest at 'https://github.com/WASdev/cloud.openshift.cartridge.wlp' must be smaller than 20480 bytes.
```

2) tried by using the command from the command line

```
rhc app-create ibmwas http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/reflect?github=WASdev/cloud.openshift.cartridge.wlp -e IBM_LIBERTY_LICENSE=L-MCAO-9SYMVC -e JVM=openjdk
```

able to create the application......but how to login to the admin consloe....i am not able to view the console link under  click on the link--->Managing your application

Comment: How are you trying to install it?

Comment: The command(s) you ran that resulted in that exception would be helpful.

Comment: Note that there is no cartridge manifest at https://github.com/WASdev/cloud.openshift.cartridge.wlp. I think you are trying to access this cartridge manifest https://github.com/WASdev/cloud.openshift.cartridge.wlp/raw/master/metadata/manifest.yml. However, it does not contain Source-URL for deployment, so why not proceed according to the README.md in the repo itself (none of the 5 methods seem to suggest what you are trying to do)? You may also want to read how to work with the cartridge reflector at http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com.

Comment: #2 is the correct approach. There isn't a Liberty-specific admin console deployed, I think what you're referring to is just mentioning that the OpenShift console can be used to start, stop, scale, etc. the app even though you can't create it from there as in your #1 approach.